# AnyLogic - Can density map be more accurate?

Tags: anylogic

Can you change the size of pixels in Density Map?

I suspect that the size of density map pixels is based on agent/pedestrian size. Can it be modified, so that pixels are smaller and leave more precise trace?

Currently, my density map leaves huge pixels that are very difficult to use as reliable information.

EDIT: Screenshot below,

[image: DensityMap pixel size]

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Can you share a screenshot? Probably you need to play with some scale settings.

Comment: Screenshot attached, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure it's not possible, the density map has a resolution of 1 meter (whatever the equivalent to 1 meter is by your scale object) and there's no way to change it (as far as I know)

But, what you have to make up for this, is the canvas object that you can find in the presentation palette. With the canvas object you can define your own resolution but you also have to code your own density map using your own personalized rules. Check the help documentation to understand how to use this and check the wondering elephants model to understand how to make changes dynamically.